# CSS Flex Width based on Lines of Text

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm not quite sure if this is possible with CSS and couldn't find anything in that direction, but I'll give it a go:

In a (Flex)-Container I want multiple(2-3) boxes/columns of text. Each column is it's own article with it's own headline, so it's not one text continuing on to the next column.

However I want the width of said columns to be flexible, so that no column wastes empty space right until the end. If a column would have empty lines, it will try to decrease it's width to create more line breaks for itself and fill that void, while the other boxes get more width to maybe decrease in number of text lines.

In any case, all columns should try to get to the same amount of Lines of Text and thus the same height of content through increasing/decreasing their width space.

/Edit: A code Example I quickly made based on https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8

As you will see, both flex Boxes will keep 50% width, even if one is much fuller than the other. I'd want them to rearrange width automatically to avoid the empty space below the text. With less width to the first box it would have more line breaks, while the second one with more width would have less line breaks. The goal is to have as little difference in lines of text count as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:20px;
  font-size: 7px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>  
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Post the code that you've tried. We can help you more effectively when we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a code example to illustrate the problem bettter, though I have not tried anything to solve it yet since I wouldn't know where to start (or if it's possible at all).

Comment: But the code sample in your question does that already: https://jsfiddle.net/sofybcge/

Comment: Not testing with Firefox. On Opera though you're right. humm. Dayum. On firefox the width only decreases as long as it's one line of text.

Comment: Did my answer helped? ... If yes, then please also accept it, if no, what can I add to make it work?

Comment: It did help, thank you! I just was disencouraged to reply that since the comment section said specifically not to post "thx" or "works" or something like that. I also upvoted but it doesnt show since I'm still new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and its `auto`, it has a history of changing its meaning, seen here:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1105111

In your case you can use `max-content` (prefixed though) to make Firefox behave

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  flex-basis: -moz-max-content;       /*  fix for Firefox  */
  
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:20px;
  font-size: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: @lainwired Thanks...and an accept anyone can do, by simply click the grey check mark just below the vote up/down arrows